# Windows 10 Cursor goes off screen to the right

Tags: windows, cursor

How can I stop my cursor from going off the right side of the screen. Would like it to stay on the screen and not get lost off to the right. Hopefully a simple fix!

Comment: A bit more information would help.  When does it "goo off the screen".  What pointing devices are being used?

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem and I found the problem in the settings after I thought my PC changed my 1600x900 to something like 1700x900.
Turns out Windows added a second monitor for some bizarre reason even though I only have one monitor.
Go to Settings>Display>Multiple displays and either select Show only monitor 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to confirm that your screen settings (desktop or laptop?) are correct for your device. I have a desktop computer and can see the mouse pointer when it is pushed all the way to the right, but my monitor has an "AUTO" feature which sizes the screen to fit the signals provided from the computer, to ensure that all of the image data is displayed.

If you have a laptop computer, the above suggestion does not apply.

If you have your computer set for multiple monitors, the mouse can disappear from any edge if the configuration is positioned appropriately for the edge at which the pointer vanishes.

A program that may be of assistance is [Mouse Trapper](https://download.cnet.com/Mouse-Trapper/3000-2317_4-75878300.html) which purports to provide restrictions and display assistance for locating the mouse pointer. Note that this is a download from download.com and the associated developer's web link fails. There may be no support for this program.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have KVM applications like Barrier or Synergy on. Sometimes they are on even when the other machine is asleep. Games can't trap my mouse if I have Barrier running.